# Split Data Set into Group and then split those groups out by age in R

Tags: r, split

I am trying to split my data set up for analyses in R. I first want to split them by group, A or B, and then split those groups up by age. I have tried using the split() function as follows:

```
Data <- read.csv("/users/SLA9DI/Documents/Test.csv")
split(Data,Data$Group)
```

But then when i try `split(Data,Data$Age)` it splits it by only age, and the same thing happens when i try `split(Data$Group,Data$Age)`. The data will be used to compare groups of people who are the same age. I also might throw in gender later, so if i could do an even further split by gender within those ages, that would be even more helpful. Example:

```
Group   Age   Data  Data2
A         13    15  10
A         13    14  6
A         18    13  2
A          8    13  8
A         12    2   2
A         14    2   2
A         16    3   2
A         16    4   4
A         16    23  5
A         16    15  4
B         13    5   5
B         13    56  6
B         18    6   1
B          8    76  6
B         12    7   3
B         14    8   2
B         16    9   2
B         16    10  5
B         16    11  6
B         16    12  7
```

Edit: Split them into groups, and then split the ages within those groups up, so i can compare the 16 Year Old Group B with the 16 Year old groups A. Further, i may want to split it even further into Gender later, to say compare a 16 Year Old **Female** in group B or group A, with 16 Year Old **Male** in Group A or B.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) containing sample data and the exact desired result you wish to get for this sample data.

Comment: maybe `split(Data,interaction(Data$Group, Data$Age))` if you really want to but there are many functions and packages available that do the split/apply/combine thing better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, rather than splitting the data multiple times, have you considered keeping the data together and using either `by()` or `aggregate()` with some functions to do your analysis?

Second, you simply need to apply the second split to all the output data. The simplest way to do this is to write a quick function that wraps and slightly modifies the built-in `split` so that you can simply pass the variable name of the variable you want to split on, rather than a vector.

The below works:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
testdata <- data.frame(Age=c(10,11,9,10,13,12,11,9,10,8,13),
                       Group=c("A","B","A","C","D","A","A","A","C","B","C"),
                       Var1=c(3,4,1,3,3,1,7,3,1,7,4))

func.split_wrapper <- function(dataframe,varname) {return(split(x = dataframe,f = dataframe[[varname]]))}

testdata.split1 <- func.split_wrapper(dataframe = testdata,varname = "Age")
testdata.split2 <- lapply(X = testdata.split1,FUN = func.split_wrapper,varname = "Group")

print(testdata.split2)

$`8`
$`8`$B
   Age Group Var1
10   8     B    7


$`9`
$`9`$A
  Age Group Var1
3   9     A    1
8   9     A    3


$`10`
$`10`$A
  Age Group Var1
1  10     A    3

$`10`$C
  Age Group Var1
4  10     C    3
9  10     C    1


$`11`
$`11`$A
  Age Group Var1
7  11     A    7

$`11`$B
  Age Group Var1
2  11     B    4


$`12`
$`12`$A
  Age Group Var1
6  12     A    1


$`13`
$`13`$C
   Age Group Var1
11  13     C    4

$`13`$D
  Age Group Var1
5  13     D    3
```

Comment: I also realize i could have just used the function 'subset(data, Age = 18 & Group = "Normal")' and stored that as an object instead of 'split()'

Comment: It is, however, generally a bad practice to use the subset command in a non-interactive environment. A better way would be processing using by() or aggregate().

Comment: Ah, I see that. I read further into it and people have been recommending the [ function instead of subset()

Answer (score 0):

I might do as following. First to obtain unique pairs of group and gender by `expand.grid()`. Then loop over the columns.

```
set.seed(1237)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(c("A","B"), 10, replace = T),
                 gender = sample(c("M","F"), 10, replace = T),
                 age = sample(c(20:25), 10, replace = T))

grid <- unique(expand.grid(df$group, df$gender))
names(grid) <- c("group", "gender")
grid

#group gender
#1      A      M
#2      B      M
#11     A      F
#12     B      F

lapply(1:nrow(grid), function(x) {
  df[df$group == grid[x, 1] & df$gender == grid[x, 2],]
})

[[1]]
group gender age
1     A      M  22
3     A      M  25
4     A      M  20
8     A      M  22

[[2]]
group gender age
6      B      M  24
9      B      M  25
10     B      M  22

[[3]]
group gender age
5     A      F  20

[[4]]
group gender age
2     B      F  24
7     B      F  25
```